# HEROKU CLI How to deploy branch and Enable automatic deploy?

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface

I'm making a script to automate environment creation on Heroku, and I'm strugling with 2 points:

- How can i Enable Automatic Deployment, using CLI? I want a command like I was clicking this button here in the Deploy tab
  [image]
- Second point is how can i deploy a branch via CLI, like I was clicking this button here:
  [image]
  NOTE: I'm using github connected to my project

Comment: Did you find an answer?